# Error:(15) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.Android Manifest

Tags: java, android, manifest

I am not able to debug my code.I have tried rebuilding,cleaning,invalidating caches and restarting,restarting my project.I still haven't been able to solve the issue.
My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.arogyam" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.arogyam.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.android.arogyam.Page2"
        android:label="page2" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" />
</application>
    </manifest>
```

> Error:(15) Tag  attribute name has invalid character ' '.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Swastik\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\24.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>    Is the error that I am getting.

Comment: lol, there is extra space at ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and its definitely not autogenerated. you might have pressed space bar by mistake while on that screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />` has a extra space, to fix: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`.

Answer (score 0):

Happened with me as well. I still cannot figure out what caused it but i restarted my android studio and error was gone. Try the following..
Restart your android studio
clean your project.  "build> clean project"
rebuild your project.  "build> rebuild project"